# using anchor instead of submit (post)

Tags: post, struts2, hyperlink, submit, anchor

I have a question, but I couldn't find a solution for my problem in Korean web community.

```
<s:form name="form1" method="post" action="products" theme="simple">
  <s:hidden name="code" value="%{code}"/>
  <s:submit type="button" name="method:selectSale" value="goPage"/>
</s:form>
```

This code has no problem.

But, I want to use "anchor" instead of "submit" tag. I just want to use hyperlink and 'post' way, not 'get'. How can I do this? Help me please~ :)

```
<s:form name="form1" method="post" action="products" theme="simple">
  <s:hidden name="code" value="%{code}"/>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.form1.submit()">goPage</a>
</s:form>
```

It doesn't work. :(

The main problem is how to get "method:selectSale".

in **struts.xml**,

```
<action name="products" class="sample.ProductsAction">
  <result>abc.jsp</result>
  <result name="selectSale">selectSale.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and then, in **ProductsAction.java**,

```
public String selectSale() throws Exception {
  // ~~~
  return "selectSale"
}
```

Ok, now, I have a question.

where do i have to put "selectSale" on code? ( using `<s:a>` or `<a:>` )

Answer (score 2):

Define a  and use it in your anchor.

```
<s:url id='IdAnchor' action='products' method='selectSale'/>

<a href="${IdAnchor}">goPage</a>
```

Regards,